# How does the log_scale of ggplot work?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am playing with changing the scale of the axis in ggplot, but I don't understand how numbers are log-scaled. For example, for a y-value of ~120000, the

```
scale_y_continuous(trans = log10_trans())
```

changes it to ~1e+05. How is this the log10 of that? Is there a way to actually change the y values to log10(y)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be confused but ... if  you actually want to log-transform your values, why not

```
ggplot(your_data,aes(x=something, y=log10(value), fill=id))+ ...
```

?  The purpose of `scale_y_log10()` is to plot the log-transformed data on a scale that shows the *original* values, but with appropriately (unevenly) spaced axis ticks ...

Answer (score 0):

`ggplot2` has two ways to specify a scale/coordinate/unit transform  : the `scale_` one and the `coord_` one. Both change the way the data is displayed and both ensure that the axis are labelled with the origin scale/unit. They however differ in a subtle way. The first one applies the transform before any statistical processing while the second only affects the display. There is no difference for a simple scatterplot but there is one for instance when doing an histogram, a conditional regression or even when computing a simple mean...